# Custom credentials provider in ServiceStack using Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, servicestack, firebase-authentication

I want to create a custom credentials provider for service stack that signs in users to Firebase using firebaseauthentication.net library. The problem I have is that after calling the authentication method, the browser keeps saying *loading* forever. This is my code:

```
 public override  bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService,string userName, string password)
    {
        return  Authenticate(userName, password).Result;
    }

    private async Task<bool> Authenticate(string userName,string password)
    {
        provider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(firebaseApiKey));
        try
        {
            auth = await provider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(userName, password);


            return auth.User != null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService,IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens,Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {

        session.FirstName = auth.User.DisplayName;
        session.Id = auth.User.LocalId;
        session.Email = auth.User.Email;

        return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use async/await in a sync method, try just using a Task, e.g:

```
private Task<bool> Authenticate(string userName,string password)
{
    provider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(firebaseApiKey));
    return provider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(userName, password)
        .Success(r => r.User != null)
        .Error(ex => false);
}
```